# Unique combination of 10 questions

Tags: data-structures

How to form a combination of say 10 questions so that each student (total students = 10) get unique combination.

I don't want to use factorial.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. There is only one unique [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of all 10 questions. If you want all of the students to get the same questions, but in a different order, you want unique [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). Search for "generating permutations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3,628,800 different permutations of 10 items taken 10 at a time.

If you only need 10 of them you could start with an array that has the values 1-10 in it. Then [shuffle the array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). That becomes your first permutation. Shuffle the array again and check to see that you haven't already generated that permutation. Repeat that process: shuffle, check, save, until you have 10 unique permutations.

It's highly unlikely (although possible) that you'll generate a duplicate permutation in only 10 tries.

The likelihood that you generate a duplicate increases as you generate more permutations, increasing to 50% by the time you've generated about 2,000. But if you just want a few hundred or less, then this method will do it for you pretty quickly.

The proposed circular queue technique works, too, and has the benefit of simplicity, but the resulting sequences are simply rotations of the original order, and it can't produce more than 10 without a shuffle. The technique I suggest will produce more "random" looking orderings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use circular queue data structure
[image]

now you can cut this at any point you like , and it then it will give you a unique string
for example , if you cut this at point between 2 and 3 and then iterate your queue, you will get :
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2 
[image]

so you need to implement a circular queue, then cut it from 10 different points (after 1, after 2[shown in picture 2],after 3,....)